# replicate Window_sum (tableau ) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions, tableau-api

I have a senario like this

```
SUBID     ID               Total   
2             0                  2
2             o                  2
2             0                   2
2              0                 2
3              1                 2
3              1                 2
3              1                2
4              1                  2
4               1               2

So now i should be getting
```

2(Subjid)-->0 (I want distinct(ID)))
    3(Subjid)--->1(I want distinct(ID))
    4(Subjid)--->1 I want distinct(ID))
    So my Total Should be  0+1+1=2
    Can we dod this in oracle i know we can do this in tbaleau as window_sum() wondering in sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand your logic correctly, you can achieve your results like so (N.B. I've assumed that `o` in your sample data for subid = 2 is an error and that it should have been a `0`):

```
with sample_data as (select 2 subid, 0 id from dual union all
                     select 2 subid, 0 id from dual union all
                     select 2 subid, 0 id from dual union all
                     select 2 subid, 0 id from dual union all
                     select 3 subid, 1 id from dual union all
                     select 3 subid, 1 id from dual union all
                     select 3 subid, 1 id from dual union all
                     select 4 subid, 1 id from dual union all
                     select 4 subid, 1 id from dual union all
                     select 4 subid, 1 id from dual)
select subid,
       id,
       sum(id_to_sum) over () total
from   (select subid,
               id,
               case when row_number() over (partition by subid, id 
                                            order by subid, id) = 1 then id end id_to_sum
        from   sample_data);

     SUBID         ID      TOTAL
---------- ---------- ----------
         2          0          2
         2          0          2
         2          0          2
         2          0          2
         3          1          2
         3          1          2
         3          1          2
         4          1          2
         4          1          2
         4          1          2
```

You can see all the various types of analytic functions that Oracle supports [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm)